# Segmentation fault after calling reset on unique_ptr

Tags: c++11, pointers, segmentation-fault, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm getting a segmentation fault while calling reset on unique_ptr:

```
Node* tree::left_rotate(Node* node) {
    Node* temp = node->right.get();
    node->right.reset(temp->left.get());
    temp->left.reset(node); // **Here is segmentation fault happens**
    if(node->right.get()) {
        node->right->parent = node;
    }
    temp->parent = node->parent;
    if(node->parent) {
        if(node == node->parent->left.get()) {
            node->parent->left.reset(temp);
            node->parent = node->parent->left.get();
        } else if(node == node->parent->right.get()) {
            node->parent->right.reset(temp);
            node->parent = node->parent->right.get();
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Node has the following structure:

```
class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node* parent;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
    public:
        Node() : data(0) {          
        }
        explicit Node(int d) : data(d),
                               parent(nullptr),
                               left(nullptr),
                               right(nullptr) {}        
};
```

gdb reports:

> Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00404ae5 in
>   std::unique_ptr >::~unique_ptr (
>       this=0xfeeefefa, __in_chrg=)
>       at C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:273
>   273             if (__ptr != nullptr)

The report from one stack-frame upper:

> ```
> #2  0x004047e8 in std::default_delete<Node>::operator() (this=0xfe1de4,
>     __ptr=0xfeeefeee)
>     at C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:81
> 81              delete __ptr;
> ```

So it seems here is double deletion. How this issue can be solved? Maybe it worths to have a temp pointer as a **shared_ptr**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Node* temp = node->right.get();
```

temp is a raw pointer to the node's right node

```
node->right.reset(temp->left.get());
```

the node's right node is reset to the temp's left node, thus the original node's right node (to which temp points) gets deleted. That means that the temp raw pointer is now pointing to a deleted node.

```
temp->left.reset(node); // **Here is segmentation fault happens**
```

As temp is deleted, dereferencing it to get it's left node lead to bad things.

A quick thought, maybe use release() instead of get() at the first place to take over ownership of the node's right node ?

Comment: Seems there is no way to implement correct rotations only with unique_ptr's.